# How to re-authenticate when upgrading the scope of the Google Drive API

Tags: php, google-drive-api

I have an web application which has a working access to the Google Drive (TeamDrive folders). It runs on WordPress and PHP. It reads the content of the drive and displays the folders/files and enables downloading the files. Everything works fine but now I would need to add a file upload functionality to it. The current scope is DRIVE_READONLY which needs to be upgraded to DRIVE allowing the write (file create) functionality.

I have changed the scope to DRIVE everywhere in the code and added the auth/drive scope in the OAuth consent screen in the Google console. However the scope in the credentials JSON file says "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly". And  when trying to upload a file the Google API responses with an error "Insufficient Permission: Request had insufficient authentication scopes.". I guess the problem is in the json and I would need to do the authentication again to upgrade the credentials to the new scope.

How do I do that when I have an application which is up and running in the production? I was not able to find any guidance how to do it. Should I do it in the console, by login with the user which is used in the application or in the CLI or how?

The code is PHP and it uses the Google API client and the classes which are working nice when reading the Drive, doing searches against the content on the Drive.

Comment: Have you created new credentials after adding the new scope, and exported and used a new JSON after that?

Comment: Do you mean the client ID and the client secret which are created in the Google API console? No, I have not not done that. I was assuming that those would still be valid and the token would need to be refreshed with the new scope.

Comment: Gotcha, you're right on that. In that case, are you sure you deleted the `token.json` that was created when you were using `drive_readonly`? If you didn't, the application will not create a new one and will use the old one.

Comment: When I delete the json which includes the token the application stops working. It cannot access the GDrive and no content is displayed. It does not create a new token either. If I undo the delete then it again works ok except the scope is read.only.

Comment: Can you share the code you're using?

Comment: I found a solution. There was a .php file which has a code for getting the authorization code and exchanging it to the credentials file. When I run it from the command line it does the trick when it cannot fine the credentials file which was deleted. Thank you for your help and time.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to run the code/script from the command line. The code does the trick when it cannot find the credentials file (which you deleted first). When you open the link in the browser and it redirects to the URL, which is set in the Google API console when you create the secret key, you find the verification code added to the end of the url. Copy-paste it to the command line and the code will get the credentials file and save it to the hard disk.

```
function getClient()
{
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setApplicationName('Web client file upload');
    $client->setScopes(Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE);
    $client->setAuthConfig('inc/client_secret_xxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com.json');
    $client->setAccessType('offline');

    // Load previously authorized credentials from a file.
    $credentialsPath = expandHomeDirectory('inc/credentials_xxxxxx.json');
    if (file_exists($credentialsPath)) {
        $accessToken = json_decode(file_get_contents($credentialsPath), true);
    } else {
        // Request authorization from the user.
        $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
        printf("Open the following link in your browser:\n%s\n", $authUrl);
        print 'Enter verification code: ';
        $authCode = trim(fgets(STDIN));

        // Exchange authorization code for an access token.
        $accessToken = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($authCode);

        // Store the credentials to disk.
        if (!file_exists(dirname($credentialsPath))) {
            mkdir(dirname($credentialsPath), 0700, true);
        }
        file_put_contents($credentialsPath, json_encode($accessToken));
        printf("Credentials saved to %s\n", $credentialsPath);
    }
    $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);

    // Refresh the token if it's expired.
    if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
        $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
        file_put_contents($credentialsPath, json_encode($client->getAccessToken()));
    }
    return $client;
}
```